# Configuring an Ubuntu DHCP server for dhcp scopes that are not directly connected

Tags: server, dhcp

I am currently configuring an Ubuntu server with ISC DHCP.
My goal is for it to hand out IP Addresses to several client subnets which are not directly connected to this DHCP Server. I have configured DHCP Relaying on the gateways of these remote networks, and I can also see the DHCP REQUESTS coming in on my server.

THe problem I have now is that unless I configure an ip address on the servers interface within those remote networks I am unable to start the isc-dhcp-server service.

Does anyone have experience setting up an isc dhcp server to serve ip addresses to clients that exist in remote networks, ie not directly connected to the servers interface?

Thanks.

Comment: In the second paragraph there is a minor case mistake in the word `the`, edit and correct that.